# Hook_node_view() to print a table?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm working on my first module. What I'd like to do is add this table http://pastebin.com/A1cbya5m function's output to the bottom of nodes. I'm not sure how to do this using hook_node_view()'s '#markup' field. I can do one line but nothing this complicated. I tried doing '#markup' => print_payment_table(), but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your function (`print_payment_table()`) you need to return a string, do not print anything (or an array which will be rendered with a theme function but this a different stuff).

Now in your `{yourmodule}.module` implement:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function {yourmodule}_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  if (...) { // Check your node->type or whatever.

    $node->content['mykey'] = array(
      '#markup' => print_payment_table($node),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to sort this element by UI (on the node type tab as a field):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_extra_fields().
 */
function {yourmodule}_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra = array();

  $extra['node'][{yourcustomcontenttype}] = array(
        'display' => array(
          'mykey' => array(
            'label' => t('Payment table'),
            'description' => t('Payment table'),
            'weight' => 10, // Default weight
          ),
        )
      );
  }

  return $extra;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't actually returning anything. So

```
'#markup' => print_payment_table()
```

will result in markup being empty. I've noticed in your function you have a lot of print statements. It would better to build a string variable in your table construction. Like:

```
$string = "<table>";
$string .= "<tr><td>".$stuff"</td></tr>";
$string .= </table>;
```

then at the end of the function, return $string.

EDIT: -----------------------
your functions should be seperated, not defined iside of each other.

So:

```
function table_builder($node){
//do stuff
   return $stuff;
}

function *my_mod*_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
   $node->'#markup' .= table_builder($node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is what I've done to fix http://pastebin.com/5XbK0yui but now I get 'Notice: Undefined variable: node in print_payment_table() ' for the first line of the function and the rest of the vars.